# SSRS expression for current month = 'Current'

Tags: reporting-services

First off I'm very new to SSRS and expressions are a steep learning curve.

I'm trying to write an expression to say if current month show text 'Current' else 'Past'. I've tried a few things like Month(Now()) = "Current" but can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it always the current month? You need to be comparing another date to the current month.

I think what you want is if a particular date field in your data is within the current month then show CURRENT, otherwise show PAST.

```
=IIF(FORMAT(Fields!END_DATE.Value, "MMyyyy") = FORMAT(TODAY, "MMyyyy"), "Current", "Past")
```

I use the FORMAT function to format the dates into month/year format - this eliminates the days so that it's just comparing the year and month.

The expression reads as

> If the month/year of the END_DATE field is equal to the month/year of
>   the current day, then return the string CURRENT else return PAST.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/expression-examples-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: The idea is 12 columns one for each month and the Jan, Feb, March etc are "Past" and Sept will be Current until next month which Sept would change to Past and Oct becomes Current.

I'll take a read of the link, thanks.

Comment: @lezs76 - If you have a field in your data that's creating the months, then just use that field with the IIF expression above (though it sounds like you may want to remove the `yyyy` for the year). If your month's are hard coded (i.e. you have a column labeled **SEPTMEBER**) then you'd have to hard code that value  `=IIF(Month(TODAY) = 9, "Current", "Past")` .

Comment: Thank you. I'll give it ago.

There is so much to learn with SSRS. I used to use Tableau which was a lot more straight forward.